# Kolmogorov's unit interval probability space

Tags: reference-request, probability-theory

Somewhere I've heard that [**Kolmogorov**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrey_Kolmogorov) proved that for all practical purposes, the [**probability space**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space) $$(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$$ that he invented could be taken without loss of generality to be the unit interval endowed with the [**Lebesgue measure**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure), $$([0,1],\mathcal L,\mu),$$
although the mappings necessary to define random variables on such a space are in general highly contrived and hence not very constructive or intuitive.  Does anyone have a reference or a pointer where to find this proof or a translation of it?

Somewhat related:
[The role of the "hidden" probability space on which random variables are defined](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23006/the-role-of-the-hidden-probability-space-on-which-random-variables-are-defined)

Comment: I believe these isomorphic spaces are called "standard." See this Wiki link for example:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_probability_space

Comment: That's right! Now I remember! Thanks for reminding me.  That was ages ago and I must have forgotten.  It's been 14 years since I took probability.